# Elasticsearch-dsl sort, find last X entries

Tags: python, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

I'm trying to find the last 30 entries into my index/doc type

I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas!

My current approach I find all the results over the last 5 minutes, then filter through the results and grab out the last 30 entries, but this is slower than the correct approach.

```
s = Search(using=es, index="history", doc_type=p)
   .filter('range', timestamp={'gte': mins})
   .extra(size=1000)
```

And I've tried

```
s = Search(using=es, index="history", doc_type=p)
   .sort("timestamp", {'order': "desc"})
   .extra(size=30)
```

Answer (score 3):

the proper way to sort on `timestamp` in descending order is either `s = s.sort('-timestamp')` or `s = s.sort({"price" : {"order" : "desc"}})`.

You were specifying your `sort` incorrectly.

Comment: Is there a typo in the second option? `s = s.sort({"timestamp" : {"order" : "desc"}})`?

Answer (score 1):

Check if **timestamp** is enabled in **doctype**.If it's enable, then only we can use **timestamp** in elasticsearch dsl.

```
#Add Query
s = Search(using=es, index="history", doc_type=p).query("query_string", query="*").sort("timestamp", {'order': "desc"})

#To specify the from/size parameters i.e for first 30 entries
s=s[0:30]

#Call elasticsearch
s.execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=sort#elasticsearch_dsl.Search.sort

timestamp will sort in ascending order.

```
s = Search().sort('timestamp')
```

timestamp will sort in descending order.

```
s = Search().sort('-timestamp')
```